# Using globbing/wildcards when Opening Files from Terminal

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, command

I have a folder `A`. Inside the folder, there are some files `a,b,c,d` and there is a subfolder, `B`, containing files `e,f,g`.

Suppose I want to open files `a,b,c,d`: then I just type `xdg-open *`. However, this also goes into subfolder `B` and opens `e,f,g` as well. What's the easiest way to open just `a,b,c,d`?

EDIT: what I really mean with the question is how to open all files in a folder, but not those contained in any subfolders.

Comment: See my updated answer, extended globbing is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

How about `find A -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec xdg-open {} \;`

That should open all files in folder A without going any further than the top level.

Comment: That'll work, but it's a pretty long command. I could alias it, but I feel as if a more elegant solution has to be possible...

Comment: As far as I'm aware that's the closest your gonna get to what you need.

Comment: This seems like the best option.

Comment: @coteyr - You can do better than this using extended globbing in Bash! See my updated answer.

Comment: @slm, I think the globbing is nice but it seems to be "harder" to use unless you want to "know" the folders content. This answer can just be run with out any special knowledge of the directory.

Comment: @coteyr - yup there's essentially 3 methods here. (1) I want to open everything except X, (2) I want to open X,Y,Z, or (3) I want to open only files contained in dir. This A covers (3), and mine covers (1) & (2). It depends on the use case, they're all equally good in their own ways.

Answer (score 1):

#### Method #1 - Shell expansions

If you know that the items you're after are sequentially named you can use shell expansions in a variety of ways.

#### Examples

```
$ xdg-open [a-d]
$ xdg-open {a..d}
$ xdg-open a* b*
```

#### Method #2 - Extended globbing

In Bash (versions 3.2+) you can use extended globbing to included everything except something, which I believe is what you're asking for.

#### Examples

```
$ xdg-open !(B)
$ xdg-open !(A|B)
```

#### Demos

I'll often times use `echo` so I can see what the globstar or extended globbing will work out to be without actually running a real command on the expanded lists of files and/or directories.

#### Example

Say for example I have the following directory of files.

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 15 20:12 a
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 15 20:23 A
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 15 20:12 b
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 15 20:12 B
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 15 20:12 c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 15 20:12 d
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 15 20:12 e
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    0 Nov 15 20:12 f
```

Now if we try out the above expansions we can see how they'd fair.

```
$ echo [a-d]
a A b B c d

$ echo {a..d}
a b c d

$ echo a* b*
a b

$ echo !(B)
a A b c d e f

$ echo !(A|B)
a b c d e f
```

#### Extended globbing

There are a variety of other methods you can use to control the way that the shell matches. For example:

```
  ?(pattern-list)   Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
  *(pattern-list)   Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
  +(pattern-list)   Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
  @(pattern-list)   Matches one of the given patterns
  !(pattern-list)   Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

You can read more about them in this Linux Journal article titled: [Bash Extended Globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing).

Comment: Or `xdg-open {a..d}`

Comment: @Bernhard - thanks, I added it to Q. You could've edited it in yourself, I don't mind.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP doesn't actually have files called `a`...`d`.

Comment: @JosephR. - yeah sorry I stubs this out today at work but then got busy and didn't' finish it as I had planned then. See it now, this was what I had in mind.

Comment: It's still dependent on file names being easy to match via single-letter globs. How can I adapt this solution to a situation where I have files called `foo`, `bar` and `glarb`?

Comment: @JosephR. - the last solution with extended globbing seems like what he wanted. Everything *except* B, no? `xdg-open !(B)`. The shell isn't psychic, it needs some strings to qualify what you want.

Comment: @JosephR. - with your example I don't see anyway to be more efficient than `xdg-open {foo,bar,glarb}`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `zsh` shell (from e.g. an interactive `bash` shell):

```
zsh -c 'xdg-open A/*(.)'
```

This would use the `.` glob modifier in `zsh` that makes `A/*` only match regular files under the `A` directory.   To also match symbolic links to regular files use `A/*(-.)` as the globbing pattern.